# How to keep current cell displaying after insertRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with 20 cells, and displaying the first cell, and I load more data on background, after data loaded, I insert 10 cells before the original 20 cells. I want the `UITableView` still displaying the orignal first cell(other means display the No.11 cell after the insertion). I use the followiing code:

```
// before insert 10 item, the UITableView(_contentTable) has 20 cell and displaying the first cell
// newItems is an NSArray has 10 item.
// insert 10 data to the data source (_contents)
if ( [newItems count] )
{
    for ( NSUInteger i = [newItems count]; i > 0; --i )
    {
        [_contents insertObject:[newItems objectAtIndex:i - 1] atIndex:0];
    }
}
// make the indexPaths for insertRowsAtIndexPaths
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:newItems.count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i<newItems.count; ++i) {
    [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }
    [_contentTable beginUpdates];
    // insert cell
    [_contentTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    // scrall to number 10 cell, make the UITableView looks like nothing happen on the background
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:0];
    [_contentTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

    [_contentTable endUpdates];
```

The problem of that code is the table will scroll up(maybe cause by `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`, I have use the parameter `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` but the table still scroll) and down(maybe cause by `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`) 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
// scrall to number 10 cell, make the UITableView looks like nothing happen on the background
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:0];
[_contentTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

You can just delete the above code if you don't want your table view to scroll.

Comment: If i don't call scrollToRowAtIndexPath, the table will display the first cell of new inserted 10 items, but not the first cell of original 20 items.